# Vaadin 8 internationalisation i18n

Tags: java, internationalization, vaadin8

I want to use internationalisation (support for multiple different languages) in a webapplication using vaadin 8. In the official documentation, I can not find anything that is supported by framework version 8. Does anybody know some example projects? Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internationalization is a common pattern in Java. You can use `ResourceBundle`s as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html). Vaadin components like labels or buttons have text that you can freely set. This means, you can get a translation from your resource bundle using the locale associated to the `UI` (call `UI.getCurrent().getLocale()`). If you do not set the locale on the `UI` yourself then Vaadin takes the language the client browser is sending which is often what you would expect as user.